# Angular - Use pipe to delay visible variable changes

Tags: angular, typescript, validation, asynchronous, pipe

I am trying to add a visible delay of 1.5 seconds to changes to my ts variable "errorsMap", which is a map of form control names (form field names) and the form errors for that particular field. Note: for whatever reason, the errors are structured as {"error message": true} as seen below.

[image]

I noticed adding a delay in the typescript code to errorsMap itself breaks my custom validations. So, I was wondering if I could just use a pipe on the html side to pass in my errors map, wait 1.5 seconds once it detects a change, then display the error visibly to the user.

I need to be able to pass in a parameter to the pipe however, because I need to check attributes I have set on the object that differentiate a dropdown menu, a text box, etc. For example, I only want there to be a delay before displaying errors on text fields (not dropdown menus.)

I am currently seeing "_isScalar" on my form instead of the error message when using my Pipe.

[image]

Here is what I have so far:

```
import { AsyncPipe } from "@angular/common";
import { Pipe, PipeTransform, OnDestroy, Injector, ChangeDetectorRef } from "@angular/core";
import { from, of, timer } from 'rxjs';
import { concatMap, delay } from "rxjs/operators";

@Pipe({ name: 'delayChanges', pure: false })
export class DelayVisibleVariableChangesPipe implements PipeTransform, OnDestroy {
  private asyncPipe: AsyncPipe;

  constructor(private injector: Injector) {
    this.asyncPipe = new AsyncPipe(injector.get(ChangeDetectorRef));
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
     this.asyncPipe.ngOnDestroy();
  }

  transform(val: any, param: any) {
    console.log(val, param[0])

    if(param[0].arrayType == 1) {
        // dropdown menu
        // return errors immediately with no delay
        return val
    } else {
        // non-dropdown menu (likely text field, add 1.5 second delay before visually displaying new error)
        return of(val).pipe(delay(1500));
    }
  }
}
```

My html implementation of the pipe:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let param of this.accountRequestParameters; let i = index">
    .....
    
    <div class="errorMsgContainer" *ngIf="this.accountRequestForm.get(param.parameterId).touched === true && this.errorsMap.get(param.parameterId) != null"> 
        <!-- <ng-container *ngFor="let item of this.errorsMap.get(param.parameterId) | keyvalue; let m = index"> -->
        <ng-container *ngFor="let item of ((this.errorsMap.get(param.parameterId)) | delayChanges:[param]) | keyvalue; let m = index">
            <!-- below allows it to display only 1 error at a time -->
            <ng-container *ngIf="m == 0">
                {{item.key}}
            </ng-container>
        </ng-container>
    </div>
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform, OnDestroy, ChangeDetectorRef } from "@angular/core";

@Pipe({ name: 'delayVisibleChanges', pure: false })
export class DelayVisibleVariableChangesPipe implements PipeTransform, OnDestroy {

    vals: Map<string, any> = new Map();

    constructor(private _ref: ChangeDetectorRef) {
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.vals = new Map();
    }

    transform(val: any, args: any) {
        // console.log(val, args[0])
        if (args[0].arrayType == 1) {
            // dropdown menu
            // return errors immediately with no delay
            this.vals.set(args[0].parameterId, val)
            return this.vals.get(args[0].parameterId)
        } else {
            // non-dropdown menu (likely text field, add 1.5 second delay before visually displaying new error)
            if (this.vals == null || this.vals.get(args[0].parameterId) != val) {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    this.vals.set(args[0].parameterId, val)
                    this._ref.markForCheck();
                    return this.vals.get(args[0].parameterId)
                }, 1500);
            } else {
                return this.vals.get(args[0].parameterId)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This mostly works but now there's a problem where if I change a fields value and there's more than one visibly invalid field it's causing the other invalid fields to flicker their message even though they haven't been changed

Comment: Sorry about that - forgot to add [0] in some places. I've corrected my answer.